# Ubuntu won't install on new computer with USB

Tags: boot, usb

I've done the following:

1. Set up a new install USB drive:
   [image: Installing image here]
2. Booted my PC which is a fresh, custom build and has nothing on it. It didn't load at all after I selected the install ubuntu option.
3. Watched as my screen went black for a few seconds, then went right back to scratch at the motherboard boot up screen.

This is the second build I've made. Both were FAT32 formatted USB drives.

Am I missing something? Do I need to set something up from the motherboard menu somehow?

Comment: Try again, but remove the `quiet splash` boot option (edit Ubuntu boot entry with `e`) and watch for error messages

Answer (score 0):

Okay this has been fixed.

The issue is a video card. I put the nomodeset option on before boot.

Now it boots to a black screen with a mouse. SIGH...